Scrolling events in JavaFx's TableView
I'm working with JavaFX using Java 8.
I've got a tableview inside of a scrollpane.
I've added an 3 event handlers to the tableview to trap for:

Scroll started
Scroll finished
Scroll any

The only event that's being registered is the Scroll Any. Even if add only one of the other two without any of the others the scroll started and scroll finished events are being registered.
I'm running my software in a Windows 10 environment on a touchscreen.
Does anyone have a work around or solution for this?
I need the scroll started and finished events more than the scroll any.
I've tried using the mouse clicked event in combination with the scrolling event to determine a scrolling finished occurrence. This did not work. When the scrolling has stopped the mouse clicked event occurs but after the mouse clicked event 2 new scrolling events get registered which makes no sense because the scrolling has stopped.

If you want debugging help, you will need to provide a [mcve].

See the Oracle event handling tutorial, it is good.  Perhaps you want to be using filters in some cases rather than handlers.  Perhaps some other handlers are consuming the events you are interested in, so your handler is never notified.

TableView includes scrolling behavior. No need to wrap it in a ScrollPane. Does this help? JavaFX scroll events handling for TableView

@Abra, thats what I thought and tried but the table did not scroll after I removed the scroll pane. I may have missed something though and will look into this and try again

I suggest you do as @jewelsea suggested in his comment, namely [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

As noted in another comment, a TableView already provides scrolling functionality. Wrapping a TableView in a ScrollPane is simply not going to work the way you want, because the table's reported size is not the size it needs to display all elements, but the size it needs to display its own scrolling viewport. There is not much API to access the internal scrolling mechanism directly, though you could subclass the skin class and access the VirtualFlow, which does expose an observable position property.

So intercepting scroll events is either going to involve some pretty unmaintainable hacks (e.g. using CSS lookups and registering event handlers/filters with the resulting nodes) or a lot of work (creating a custom skin for the table view). Any time you try to modify behavior of controls, especially very complex controls such as a TableView, you are going to run into these kinds of issues. Really, you should not care when the user scrolls in the table; the table manages the scroll events itself, displaying the appropriate cells. Maybe there is another way to do whatever you are trying to do.

Probably an xyproblem.  See the link to find out what to do about it.

I agree with everyone else here: This is either an XY Problem or you need to provide an actual [mre]. That said, there is at least one bug (JDK-8248124) on Windows when it comes to SCROLL_STARTED / SCROLL_FINISHED.

The problem turned out to be putting the TableView in a ScrollPane.
The solution was putting the tableview into a StackPane.
